# .htaccess redirect a subdomain address to that of main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following address

```
http://subdomain.example.com/content/category/25/72/138
```

I would like to redirect it to

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=73&Itemid=132
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^com_([^/]*)/25/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?option=$1&view=$2&id=$3&Itemid=$4 [L]`
```

But why did you skip `25` in the URL?

Comment: Addressing is totally new. I have many addresses like this. That is they should be kept as is.
http://subdomain.example.com/content/category/25/72/138 --> http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=73&Itemid=132